# Angular Promise: $q reject return html?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-promise, q

is it possible to return an html file when $q.defer reject happens? i am loading a map using the below function, the problem is when the deferred.reject() happens, the entire map becomes blank. I tried an alert function inside the reject to this is an error and it works , but the user page is still blank and user cant navigate out unless they hit back page. So,is it possible to show an entire html file  like deferred.reject('test.html') something like that. I am new to java script and programming in general.

```
  loadData = () => {
    let deferred = this.$q.defer();

    this.siAsset.getAllcomponents().then((resp) => {
        if(resp.statusCode){
            deferred.reject('No Mappable Assets Found');
        }else{
            deferred.resolve(resp)
        }
    }, (err) => {
        if(err =="TypeError: Cannot read property 'components' of null"){
            deferred.reject('No Mappable Assets Found');
        }else{
            this.$log.error(err)
        }
    })
    return deferred.promise
}
```

so essentially the loaddata loads things like markers and diagrams inside a map, the problem is when choosing a user with no map data, the entire page becomes blank , this is the ui route setup for the page

```js
.config(($stateProvider) => {
    "ngInject";
    $stateProvider
    .state('map', {
      url: '/map',
      component: 'map',
      resolve:{
        loadData:(siMapUtils) => {return siMapUtils.loadData()},
        isAuthenticated: (siUser) => { 
          return siUser.isAuthenticated()
        },
        isAccessible: (siRoutePermissions) => {
          return siRoutePermissions.validate({
            permissionModules:['MAP_READ']
          })
        }
      }
    });
})
```

Comment: service side issue... you have some error redirect or error handler on server, you can see error details in html

Comment: What is returned in the successful response; is it also html? There are multiple ways you can do what you want on the server or client.

Comment: I would establish a standard for the data being returned. You can return default, but valid, values that won't break your view.

Comment: at the moment i dont need to see the error code, maybe i can just console it for other developers. I am currently putting deferred.resolve(resp) on the place of reject, this way at least the navigation bar show up so user can navigate out of it ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better and easy solution to where i used state go to shoot the user to an existing page

```js
                deferred.reject(this.$state.go('administration.assets'))
```